# How to dump SQLite in-memory database into file with ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am using `System.Data.SQLite.dll` to make use of the SQLite in-memory database. After the program finishes, I would like to dump the in-memory database into a .db3 file for next use. How can I achieve this in C#?

Comment: I would like to code like:
<code>
using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=:memory:")
{
    conn.Open();
    
    // do insert, update...
    
    // how to dump data into a file? 
    
    conn.Close();
}
</code>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is not built-in functionality to accomplish this in System.Data.SQLite.dll. The functionality does however exist in the sqlite3.exe client maintained along with the SQLite core.

This is how I would do it with system.data.sqlite.dll:

1. Obtain SQL statements to create new database structure.

   ```
   select sql from sqlite_master where name not like 'sqlite_%';
   ```
2. Obtain names of all user tables.

   ```
   select name 
   from sqlite_master 
   where type='table' and name not like 'sqlite_%';
   ```
3. Create the on-disk database in some new SQLiteConnection.
4. Execute all previously obtained SQL statements to create the database structure in the on-disk database.
5. Close the separate connection to the on-disk database.
6. Attach the on-disk database to the in-memory database.

   ```
   attach 'ondisk.db3' as 'ondisk';
   ```
7. For each user table obtained earlier, copy the content from the in-memory to the on-disk database.

   ```
   insert into ondisk.TableX select * from main.TableX;
   insert into ondisk.TableY select * from main.TableY;
   ```